# How to use multiple nodes in a cluster to process huge data - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive, distributed-computing

I have a 15 node cluster which I am planning to use for processing data in the range of 90 million rows(Hive table) / per day. The data is present in one of the nodes as a hive table and I am using something like the following command,

```
with hive.connect(host = 'hostname of that node', port= 10000, authMechanism='LDAP', user='username', password='pass') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('select * from tablename')
        do_not_touch_this_data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetch())
```

The problem here is the query is running for more than 8 hours to load all the data into python. This is because the package takes all the data and loads it into the memory of this particular node. Even after loading, I am not able to run even basic commands like count / EDA. It is taking a lot of time for each command. This is because 128 GB RAM of this particular node in the 15 node cluster is overloaded.

I want to make use of other nodes memory as well in order to read / process / do EDA with the data. Can anybody suggest a way to use these nodes in python, so that, the commands would run much faster and I would be able to use all the nodes? I am a beginner to distributed computing and I am guessing there should be a way to make use of all the nodes. Also whether reading all the data into python memory is a good practice?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Distributed systems is a large and complex topic that's best left to experts. You're using Pyhon, Pandas, and Hive. You should just switch to Spark, which has its own `DataFrame` abstraction similar to Pandas and supports reading from Hive tables but will handle distributing the data across your servers for you. You should be able to easily translate any operations you're doing in Pandas directly to Spark.